# Differences while using pg_dump from a container Vs. from my host machine

Tags: postgresql, containers, pg-dump

I'm trying to build snapshot for testing of my databases on local container (easy to ship around my peers).
when running pg_dump from my host machine (mac laptop) the results is extensive and the output has all the required tables.
while, when trying the same command from within the container, it sometimes fail or the result is slim.

I'm using official [postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).

---

local

> pg_dump --version
>
> pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 11.4

container

> pg_dump --version
>
> pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 11.5 (Debian 11.5-1.pgdg90+1)

---

the obvious solution is to run it from the host, but that won't help creating 'out-of-the-box solution' for testing.
any idea how to get thing work from within the container?

Comment: Are you connecting with the same user to the same database in both cases?  Can you show us the arguments you are using?

Comment: same use and connection string

> pg_dump -U my_user -h my_host -p 5439 -sc dbname

Comment: If you connect using `psql -U my_user -h my_host -p 5439 dbname` can you see all of the tables and read their contents? This smells like a configuration problem such as missing permissions, or maybe the data you're expecting to see was never actually imported.

Comment: Is port 5432 of the container mapped to 5432 on the host operating system?